# show a bootstrap modal on page load in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am a newbie in asp.net. I want to show a simple bootstrap modal on pageload in my page. The application is written in asp.net. I wrote the code like we do in php to show a modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But its not working.. I know the way we code in asp.net is different from php. As I am unaware of the concepts in .net I am unable to get this done.
 Can anyone help me please..

Comment: Start by adding an ID of `myModal` to the modal. That is no different from php.

Comment: Added..But not working..!

Comment: You can add it like this: `<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">` - what thing doesn't work?

Comment: See https://bootstrap.build/app for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `id` is missing. Just added `id="myModal"` in your html and it's working.

If it's still not working then please check that you have included `jquery` or not. Then check for `bootstrap`. Note that `jquery` must be appear before `bootstrap`.

You can check working demo below where only `id` is added into your code.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case its not working .. In console I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`. I have updated the jquery version and all

Comment: Please verify that your `bootstrap` js is getting loaded or not. And also check whether your `bootstrap` js version contains functionality of `modal`. Otherwise you can use same cdn url I've used in my answer.